# ProgressBar.Tap event not firing?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, progress-bar, windows-phone

I have a large ProgressBar in my xaml page:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="prog" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Tap="prog_Tap"/>
```

When I tap it, it's supposed to throw an exception:

```
private void prog_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

However, nothing happens when I tap the ProgressBar. Is there something wrong with my code, or is this a Silverlight bug?

Comment: Strange problem. I put it in a grid for now and used the grid's tap event

Answer (score 1):

I think ProgressBar doesn't support hittest by default. Try to set `IsHitTestVisible="True"`, that should work.

Comment: I checked and the progress bar is hit test visible.